# in main() , Not Declared in Scope

Tags: c++, class

On compiling the below code, I get the error,

> in int main(), t1 was not declared in this scope.

I am using `g++`. In `main()` I have already declared `t1`,`t2` and `t3`. Then why am I getting this error ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class time
{
    int hours;
    int minute;
public:
    void getdata(int h,int m)
    {
    hours=h;
    minute=m;
    }   
    void putdata(void)
    {   
        cout<<"\n Hours = "<<hours;
        cout<<"\n Minutes = "<<minute;
    }   
    void sumtime(time ,time);

};
void time::sumtime(time t1,time t2)
{ 
    minute=t1.minute+t2.minute;
    hours=minute/60;
    minute=minute%60;
    hours = hours + t1.hours + t2.hours;
}

int main()
{
    time t1,t2,t3;
    t1.getdata(2,45);
    t2.getdata(3,30);
    t3.sumtime(t1,t2);
    cout<<"\n T1 ... "<<t1.putdata();
    cout<<"\n T2 ..."<<t2.putdata();
    cout<<"\n T3 ... "<<t3.putdata();

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I got the same error message, but it was preceded by another: `error: expected ‘;’ before ‘t1’` on the line `time t1,t2,t3;`. The first reported syntax error is the most important. Syntax errors can often confuse the compiler, making later error messages meaningless.

Comment: It's extremely annoying that `#include <iostream>` can make declarations in `<time.h>` directly (or even indirectly) visible, but we seem to be stuck with it.

Comment: just to be pedantic, the lines like `cout<<"\n T1 ...<<t1.putdata();` won't compile, as `putdata()` does not return a `ostream`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your class named `time` is likely name-colliding with the [C Standard Library function of the same name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time).

My recommendation would be to put your class and related functions in their own namespace.

I'd also recommend that you not `using namespace std`, but instead just bring in the things you actually need, such as `using std::cout`.  Even better, avoid `using` altogether and just be explicit in your code.

Comment: Or just don't include the entire `std` namespace.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit:  Although a good suggestion, that may not do the trick here.

Comment: If that is the case, will using a different name solve the issue? Let's say, I use "times" instead.

Comment: @John Dibling, if OP is conflicting with `std::time` (which would be my bet) it would do the trick. But yes, your answer would definitely solve the problem.

Comment: Or rename your time class. :-)

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit:  `time`, as defined by the C Standard Library, is not in the `std` namespace.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit Unfortunately C++ allows C standard library names to be pulled into the global namespace. So you could get `std::time`, `time`, or both.

Comment: @JohnDibling, but `std::time` is in the `std` namespace. @juanchopanza clears this up.

Comment: @gotolabeladi:  I suggest you try what I posted but, yes, that will solve the problem.

Comment: I'm really not sure why someone chose to downvote this answer.

Comment: Because some people are stupid. And maybe because `time::putdata()` returns `void` which conflict with `cout<<"\n T1 ...<<t1.putdata();`

Answer (score 0):

There is one error in this program.
In `main()` function

```
cout<<"\n T1 ... "<<t1.putdata()
```

for above line `putdata()` will return `void` type but `cout` need `char` or convertible type. So it should be something like:

```
cout<<"\n T3 ... ";
t3.putdata();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to rename your class to `Time` (not `time`), because the time class already exists in the namespace std.

Comment: You didn't answer the question that was actually asked:  why is this an error?

Comment: Right -- and the point is that you didn't say that in your answer.